Rebase part of one repository history on top of a similar but different repository
We have a couple of repositories, let's call them RA and RB which are similar but not the same. RA is a export of an SVN repostiory were some libraries were extracted in the export process and RB is the same repository but with the libraries still commited in the history of the repository. RA was an attempt to use submodules but the process of submodules did not fit our workflow too well. RB's latest commit is still at the point of which we exported the project to RA.
RA-a-b-c-d-e-f-g...

RB-no new commits

Now we are attempting to rebase all the changes that have happened since on RA to RB to get the same project layout we had before, which was libraries are just part of the code. The biggest caveat is that the history has to be retained, otherwise a merge did work just fine. This seems trivial, especially since RB has no new commits, so in theory their starting point is the same, though their commit history is not, they do not share any SHAs.
RA-a-b-c-d-e-f-g...
   | | | | | | |
   V V V V V V V
RB-a-b-c-d-e-f-g...

What I have tried is:
cd RB
git remote add remoteRA ../RA
git fetch --all
git lfs install
git lfs fetch --all
git rebase -X theirs --onto master <RB-HEAD-commit> <RA-HEAD-commit>

# Also tried the same but with git merge instead of rebase

To which I expect it to almost just work, I get minor merge-conflicts, such as with the libraries changing to submodules and some conflicting submodules SHAs, but nothing major and some small issues with git lfs which more or less gets solved by the fetch or GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE=1. I would have thought that since the history is already "set in stone" it would handle it a little more elegantly, but that is not the biggest issue. Since we started to use submodules I end up with a bunch of extra submodule folders containing <submodule-name>~<submodule-SHA>, example Libs/LibraryOne~9d47f69c.... When doing the rebase git seems to handle submodules but I still end up with this completely ruined history full of wrongly named submodule folders.
I am not sure on how to proceed. Since I am to integrate the submodules back into the project with history, maybe filtering the libraries out completely as submodules is the way and then just re-integrating the submodules again with history? The issue then becomes that the history is close to useless as we don't know what commit had what submodule commit anyways.
The process i described earlier did work for integrating back the submodules, however the we get approx. 35000 commits of which many get a duplicate per library that was changed, instead of the clean commit history we had prior in SVN. So preferably I would like to, as described, rebase it ontop of this new export, RB.
It also seems really odd becuase git merge --allow-unrelated-histories remoteRA/master seems to be the recommended way on every post I open but I did not get preserved history, it all ended up as one commit...
Hopefully someone more versed in git than me can at least nudge me in the right direction.

You chose RA as a new base for RB. All commits (including those adding submodule etc) are part of RA, so they become part of RB. I'd cherry-pick those commits from RA into RB instead.

"the history has to be retained" -- what precisely do you mean with that? Code? Commit messages? Commit IDs (SHA)?

What commit is master pointing to in each of the repositories?

@UlrichEckhardt "the history has to be retained" refers only to the changes and commit messages from RB to RB->HEAD and then RA to RA-HEAD is kept intact. That is, any history in RA before the common start-date of RA and RB can be ignored.

@TTT for RB, master points to the last commit on the day we switched from SVN to Git. Master for RA points to the latest changes in our new Git repository that we have been using since we moved from SVN to Git. As per the poorly constructed git diagram I wrote in the post.

It looks like the rebase command isn't quite right. It's not entirely clear what master refers to in your question, but we can sidestep that by using the commit IDs you provided instead:
cd RB
git remote add remoteRA ../RA # Note "remote add" instead of "add remote"
git fetch --all

# For sanity purposes, create a new branch
git switch -c testing remoteRA/g # point "testing" to the current remote
# Now rewrite ONLY a through g
git rebase RA testing --onto RB

In words, that says,

Take all of the commits reachable by testing which aren't reachable by commit ID RA (this leaves a through g), and replay each of those 7 commits, one by one, onto RB.

Note that if you were also calling your branches RA and RB in addition to the repo names, then you could restate this in your wording like:
git rebase RA testing --onto <RB-HEAD-commit>

Here testing is pointing to <RA-HEAD-commit>, so if you weren't using a temp testing branch, it would be:
git rebase RA <RA-HEAD-commit> --onto <RB-HEAD-commit>

If you re-order it like you had with --onto first, then it would become:
git rebase --onto <RB-HEAD-commit> RA <RA-HEAD-commit>

Note that RA is the parent of a, so that would be the same as:
git rebase --onto <RB-HEAD-commit> a~1 <RA-HEAD-commit>

I doubt you'll be able to refer to commit RA or a~1 by name, unless you still have a branch pointing to that commit.
Side Note: per the wording of the question, I'm guessing you won't have conflicts during the rebase, in which case using -X theirs wouldn't be necessary.

As per the post, I kept getting conflicts regarding submodules and the submodule folders with ~<commit id> popping up, so -X theirs was an attempt to rectify/ignoring any "old" changes in favor of the new, but it seemed to not work.

I could not get this to work. This did rebase without conflicts initially. But I had to pull to actually complete the git history. But then the old history from RB for the libraries were, as it seems, overwritten by the history of the same folders in RA, as in RA they are deleted and in the new history after rebase, the libraries folders have no history.

@Dequilla I'm not sure what you mean by "I had to pull to actually complete the git history". A "pull" will either do a merge or a rebase without --onto, neither of which is what you want here.

Having done the rebase, running git log showed no change to the history. Figured it was because it just didn't have to "locally" since the changes came from RA. Seems to be true since a pull fixed that.
Overall, I did succeed with your rebase version, however, the result seemed similar to that of my attempt, with the exception of me solving the merge-conflicts better this time.
